# server address changed after set url

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I ran set-url and now i'm not able to serve my page anymore.
I'm still not sure if that is the reason

**before:** Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000 **- > it was working**

**now :** Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000 /carlashub.github.io// **- >broken**

**ERROR `/' not found.**

This is the command i'm running to serve :
 **bundle exec jekyll serve -- watch --baseurl ""**

I also tried to remove the base url from the config.yml and run  $ jekyll serve --baseurl '/' this is the output :

```
    HP@carlas MINGW64 /c/xampp/htdocs/carla201 (gh-pages)
WARN: Unresolved specs during Gem::Specification.reset:
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      listen (~> 3.0)
      rouge (< 4, >= 1.7)
      rb-fsevent (>= 0.9.4, ~> 0.9)
      rb-inotify (>= 0.9.7, ~> 0.9)
WARN: Clearing out unresolved specs.
Please report a bug if this causes problems.
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:313:in `check_for_activated_spec!': You have already activated public_suffix 3.0.3, but your Gemfile requires public_suffix 3.0.1. Prepending `bundle exec` to your command may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:31:in `block in setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:26:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.16.2/lib/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:50:in `require_from_bundler'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/jekyll-3.8.5/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/jekyll:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Your case look like this issue: https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/1432 . Right?

Comment: It does. and i tried that first! not results

Comment: remove `--baseurl ""`?